# Django Model check data type integrity before saving

Tags: mysql, django

I have a Django project where I am forced to do a raw sql query (so not using a Model for saving this information), but I still want to check for correctness or data types on some of the arguments of this query. Let's say I have this model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=768)
    product_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, blank=True)
```

And I want to do a simple Raw SQL query like:

```
insert into mymodel (name, product_count, paid_amount) values (%s, %s, %s);
```

Now I know I can do this with Django models directly, but please let's think that **I am forced to do this with raw SQL** (also my real query is very different that this one, I am just presenting an example to expose my case).

Now, I have three variables I want to insert on my Raw SQL, but for each of them I want to check data type, so before calling the database `insert`, I want to use my `Django` model for checking its type:

- check if my `name` variable is actually string (and maybe that it won't pass 768 characters, but with only checking if it is string is ok).
- check if my `product_count` variable is a positive integer.
- check if my `paid_amount` is a decimal number.

I would love if it would be something like this:

```
m = MyModel(name=name, product_count=product_count, paid_amount=paid_amount)
if m.check_types(): # that could give an error if some of the fields are wrong.
    cursor.execute("""insert into mymodel (name, product_count, paid_amount) values (%s, %s, %s ...
    ...
```

`Django` has something like that `check_types()` method?

Comment: may be the [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a form, populate it with the data and check if it's valid.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=768)
    product_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, blank=True)

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'product_count', 'paid_amount']
```

Then, your code would look something like:

```
 data = {'name': name, 'product_count': product_count, 'paid_amount': paid_amount }
 model_form = MyModelForm(data)
 if model_form.is_valid():
     cursor.execute("""insert into mymodel ...""")
```